# Outlook 2010 Lost Folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Have been using Outlook 2010 3 weeks and all is well. Today I have 'lost' a folder and cannot locate it or the several associated sub folders. When I search for the messages I can find them; but in properties all it says is 'personal folders'. How can I locate the folder by typing in the name of the folder? I have tried manually without success. Appreciate any guidance Thank you

Comment: Thanks Steve. The missing ones are a subfolder, and all in the same PST file as the many other folders that are OK. I heve done a manual search and can't find them at all. When I search for a particular mail that should be in the sub folder, I can find it, but it does not tell me where the sub folder is!

Comment: Are you using Exchange to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Windows Start button** and in the **Start Search area**, type in the file name that you've already searched for and found in outlook, but still have not found the folder where it resides. Or, type in the name of the folder in the Start Search area.  You'll be presented with an Explore view of all files with that name on your system.  The location path will show under the Folder header.

Answer (score 0):

Personal Folders are usually associated with an external *.PST file, which is a separate location to the mailbox.

Try doing a search on your hard drive for any files with a .PST file extension.  Once you know their location, add them by going to (Outlook) File > Data File Management > Add.

(it is a bit odd that they could be found if the personal folders were not already added though)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the path with a bit of VBA

http://vboffice.net/sample.html?lang=en&mnu=2&smp=65&cmd=showitem

Public Sub GetItemsFolderPath()

```
Dim obj As Object
Dim F As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Msg$
Set obj = Application.ActiveWindow
If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.Inspector Then
    Set obj = obj.CurrentItem
Else
    Set obj = obj.Selection(1)
End If
Set F = obj.Parent
Msg = "The path is: " & F.FolderPath & vbCrLf
Msg = Msg & "Switch to the folder?"
If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = F
End If
```

End Sub